# javascript basic not working - undefined $

Tags: javascript, undefined

I'm not good with JS, but work with it a lot. This is a case where the script in question has worked fine, then I put the exact same code on a new page, and it does not work. FF error console gives this message: "$ is undefined" on line 60.
Line 60 looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

The whole script looks like this (there are actually 52 poems- 1 for ea week - in the script:

```
var poems = [
      "A single leaf falls,<br>Then suddently another<br>Stolen by the breeze<br><br>Ransetsu",
      "For rice-planting  women<br>There's nothing  left unspoiled<br>But their song<br><br>Raizan"  
];

var now = new Date();
var onejan = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
var doy = Math.ceil((now - onejan) / 86400000);
var week = parseInt(doy / 7, 10);
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".poembox1").html(poems[week]);
});
```

Question: why did this work before and now not, or more to the point, what needs to happen to this script to get it to work, in particular the $(document).ready(function(){   line.
thanks
JSC, Boulder
****************THIS IS A RECORD!**********
Stackoverflow is amazing. I have been using forums since 2004, and never had a question answered by four people within 6 minutes. NO, I did not include jquery library, and YES, when I included it, the thing worked fine!!!!! 
thank you.
Amazing. 
wow. 
ok enuf
JSC

Comment: I just did, and that fixed it. thanx@!!!

Comment: Don't forget to click a checkmark on an answer below as correct.  jleedev got it in first.

Answer (score 5):

Here, the answer *is* “Use jQuery”.

The page from which you copied this script must have included it, so find the `<script src=...>` tag and include that as well.

Comment: more correctly, the answer is "make sure the page includes a reference to the jQuery library before the code you are using so that you know that the browser knows how to use jQuery (and by reference the shorthand operator $)" but ... this is close enough. ~~ Which you got in the re-edit :p

Comment: It was intended as a jab against all those answers which respond to ordinary JavaScript questions with “Just use jQuery!” My sarcasm is usually transparent.

Comment: @Oliver:  "Use jQuery" happens to be a correct answer in this case!

Comment: @Oliver:  There are different ways to describe the same thing... that's why we have voting.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery won't work if jQuery library is not linked to your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to include the [jquery](http://jquery.com) library in your code. Include it. If still it gives error then check for `noConflict()`

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.haikudesigns.com/assets/js/haiku-week.js"></script>

and this is calling the function:
<div class="poembox1">&nbsp;</div>

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the jQuery include:

```
<script src='/path/to/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$` is an object used in the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library. You need to include the jQuery library in your code to use it.

Include jQuery by adding the following line after the `<head>` tag in your HTML (before you use code that relies on jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the jQuery framework to use it's syntax.
You may do that as the guys said or use google's as follows:-